# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. All list objects have unique id but I still get an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some objects in data.json file looking like this:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "srcImg": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5a/Wearethechampions.jpg",
    "name": "We are the champions"
}]
```

All id inside of json are unique.
There is my react code:

```
function MusicLi({ item }) { //we take item from map() in MusicList function 
  return (
    <div>
      <li key={item.id}>
        <img src={item.srcImg}/>
        <p>{item.name}</p>
      </li>
    </div>
  );
}

function MusicList() {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => ( //data - imported json
        <MusicLi item={item}/> // send item object to MusicLi function
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You need to put the `key` on your `div`.

Comment: Your HTML doesn't look very valid with that `<li />` not being wrapped in an `<ul />` or an `<ol />`

Comment: still get an error

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function MusicLi({ item }) { //we take item from map() in MusicList function 
  return (
    <div key={item.id}>
      <li>
        <img src={item.srcImg}/>
        <p>{item.name}</p>
      </li>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Move the `key` to your top element.

Comment: A real good and also correct answer would hint to keep the key within the `</li>` and skip the surrounding / wrapping `</div>` instead. In addition it could have provided the suggestion of replacing the `</div` of the `MusicList` component with either `</ol>` or `</ul>`

Answer (score -1):

You will required to update the code like

```
function MusicLi({ item }) {
  return (
    <div key={`sample_${item.id}`}>
      <li key={item.id}>
        <img src={item.srcImg}/>
        <p>{item.name}</p>
      </li>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can define every element unique key.

Comment: Solution was to replace code from MusicLi to inside of MusicList render method

Comment: It is doesn't matter you can create a separate function and call it inside the loop. If you use that approach then you need to define the element unique key.